# Why is this fulltext query on fewer rows slower than the same query on more rows?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains, database-performance

This query takes 21 seconds:

```
SELECT Top 50 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY aDate DESC) AS Row, aID, aHeadline, aAuthor, aDate, TopStory, SiteSectionID, PrintSection, aSummary, small_image, aBody FROM articles 
WHERE aLive = -1 AND full_story = -1 AND aDate >= '9/3/2012' AND aDate <= '10/3/2012' AND (Contains((aAuthor,aBody,aHeadline,aSubhead,aSummary), '"kodak"')) 
ORDER BY aDate DESC
```

This query takes 1 second:

```
SELECT Top 50 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY aDate DESC) AS Row, aID, aHeadline, aAuthor, aDate, TopStory, SiteSectionID, PrintSection, aSummary, small_image, aBody FROM articles 
WHERE aLive = -1 AND full_story = -1 AND aDate >= '9/3/2002' AND aDate <= '10/3/2012' AND (Contains((aAuthor,aBody,aHeadline,aSubhead,aSummary), '"kodak"')) 
ORDER BY aDate DESC
```

The only thing that is different is the date range.  Without the contains portion of the queries, they return 255 and 39,106 rows respectively.

It doesn't make sense to me that the fulltext query against 39K rows is faster than the same against 255 rows.

The second query without the contains takes nearly 2 minutes.  That makes it even more confusing to me.

Other notes:

- aDate is a datetime field with a non-unique index
- aLive is an int field with a non-unique index
- full_story is an int field with a non-unique index

Comment: Check the execution plan

Comment: Typical optimizer problem. Cardinality misestimation.

Comment: If you run the first query, then the second, and then the first query again, does it still run in 21 seconds? I am wondering if the first query is slow because it is the first time it is run and it is generating the execution plan, so the second query is reusing that plan and therefore running faster.